# What is the weight of ballistic recovery systems?

Tags: airframe-parachute, quadcopter

How much does a Ballistic Recovery Systems parachute system weigh?  I wouldn't want to use a personal quadcopter or jetpack without one.  I wonder if they could be made small and light enough for a small JB-9 type jetpack.

Comment: A ballistic recovery chute would not help you on a jetpack as you would not be flying high enough to deploy it successfully.

Comment: It does on the Martin Jetpack and the point of having the rocket propelled parachute is so that it can deploy at low altitudes quickly.  I think they should scale it down, use all carbon fiber to lighten it up and integrate it into their own jetpack design....  expand and become vertically integrated !

Comment: You might consider a standard backpack parachute instead.

Comment: Not sure where this was missed, but the point of a Ballistic Recovery Systems rocket propelled parachute is to deploy a fully inflated parachute much quicker than a standard backpack parachute.  Therefore, at low altitudes it will allow you to continue to enjoy a bite of cheesecake, a walk around a lake and playing with your dogs whereas a standard backpack parachute in this case would be mean your dead.

Comment: A BRS system the size of Boba Fett's backpack with the rocket sticking out the top is what I'm thinking.  https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=boba+fett&view=detailv2&&id=E808371130693DDF13DB4E7BCD007B59D877EA81&selectedIndex=0&ccid=mb4%2fK%2b2G&simid=608024399114013564&thid=OIP.M99be3f2bed868f71f6a96236d22e5dcfH0&ajaxhist=0

Answer (score 8):

The [smallest BRS listed here](http://www.brs-vertrieb.de/specifications/) is certified up to 600 pounds (272 kg) of aircraft weight. That should be more than enough for a small jetpack or personal quadcopter. This system weighs about 22 pounds (10 kg), not counting anything required to install it.

As GdD mentioned, altitude may be an issue. The [FAQ for a Cessna 182](http://www.brsaerospace.com/cessna_182_faq.aspx) mentions an altitude loss of about 300 feet, and that is with a rocket deployment.

They make systems for [many different types of aircraft and ultralights](http://www.brsaerospace.com/advice_to_owners.aspx), some probably smaller than the 600 pound limit listed above. You should contact them if you have a serious interest in such a system.